# SQL Server Concatenation of Different Data Types

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to concatenate different data types in T-SQL that does not require to convert everything to the same data type?
Below code show the scenario:

```
DECLARE @weight INT = 50
PRINT 'The weight is' + @weight + 'years old'
```

Comment: post the sample input

Comment: No - if you want to concatenate together string literals , then you must cast or convert your other values to a string type, too

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you concatenate, if you use + you'll need an explicit conversion, but you can use the concat function and it'll implicitly convert the parameters for you. Having said that doing things explicitly is very often a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version **< SQL Server 2012** , you have only one option which is to `+`. In this case, you are left with no other option than explicit conversion.

But, with the versions starting from SQL Server 2012 you can use `CONCAT` which does implicit conversions for you.